# What is the difference between origin/master and master?

Tags: git

What is the difference between (basically I want to rebase my branch with master):

```
<on my branch at this prompt>
$ git rebase origin/master
$ git rebase master
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Origin/master is the master branch that is in the remote repository (Github). Master is on your local repository (your local machine).

Comment: It might be helpful to explain the difference between rebasing from master and origin/master