# Whats the difference between developer master and remote master when use?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-remote

Before I ask this question, I have searched SO, find a related post here:
[What is the difference between origin/master and master?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19502876/what-is-the-difference-between-origin-master-and-master)

I know the origin/master is in the remote repo, and master in our local repo.

But, I want to know wether only the location difference? If in the local repo to pull/push origin, is there some difference to precipitate?

[image]

You see upper snapshot, DEV1, DEV2... clone from origin repo.
now DEV1, DEV2... all will have a master branch, and they can also create other branches such as `dev1-branch`.

I have a question:

whether DEV1 can push to origin repo using dev1-branch directly? Or master use DEV1's master merge dev1-branch, then can push to origin repo?

Answer (score 0):

First, the local master and the origin master relationship:
If the local repo clone the origin repo to your local computer, the cloned repo will have a default master branch(`local master`), when you pull or push the local master to origin, it will affect to the origin master.

Second, if you in your local repo have a `dev1-branch`, you push to origin, the origin will generate the `dev1-branch`, will not affect the `origin master`. if you want merge the `dev1-branch` to `origin master`, you have two choice.
1.In your local repo, you merge the `dev1-branch` to `master`, then you can push to `origin master`.
2.You can push the `dev1-branch` to origin repo as `origin dev1-branch`, then in the origin server to merge the `origin dev1-branch` into `origin master`.